# Python/PyQt5 fullscreen application on Windows 10 in Tablet mode

Tags: windows, python-3.x, windows-10, pyqt5, pywin32

I have a PyQt5 application running on Windows 10 with touchscreen device and I need to run it in fullscreen (the taskbar has to be hidden also in tablet mode).

In Classic mode, all is working fine.
In Tablet mode, I have 2 problems:

1. when I launch the main window sometimes it launches but the start screen shows up in foreground: I need to look manually for running applications and click on my application in order to see it on the screen.
2. while using my application I can click on button to open a preferences dialog and opening it ends up in the same behaviour above: the start screen is shows up in foreground and I need to look manually for running applications and click on my application in order to see it on the screen.

This is very annoying behaviour.

Basically what I do is a showFullscreen() on the main window when it's launched and a dialog.exec_() on the dialog in order to show it as modal dialog.

I tried to look around for help in order to solve this issue but I really found nothing useful. I read about other people having similar behaviour but I found no solution.

Do you have suggestions on how to handle this in Python 3.5 ?

Thank you in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I was able to find the cause that was keeping the window going minimized while in tablet mode in Windows 10 so I decided to write it here in the hope it could help someone else.

The issue was related (at least for my specific case) to the fact that were some QWidget (also custom classes extending QWidget) with no given parent passed in constructor (i.e. parent=None).
And since I found this in the [QWidget's documentation page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#top-level-and-child-widgets):

> A widget without a parent widget is always an independent window (top-level widget).

I parsed my code and set the parent to those QWidgets and the issue now it seems solved to me.

As a side note: I found I had to set the parent in the constructor also to some (but not necessarily to all) QWidget's subclasses (i.e. QScrollArea, QScrollWidget, QFrame, and so on..)... I really don't know why, but anyway to set a parent in the constructor seems to me a best practice, so I go by this way from now on.